# Gets AWS VPC subnet info

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I was hoping to get a quick review of a script I wrote for retrieving AWS VPC Subnet information.  Any and all ideas welcome. I am looking specifically for logic enhancements, and optimizations to make the code more pythonic. Also, I was initially constructing a dictionary, however I had to adjust since many of the aws values have "-" hyphens. :-(

One note - I am using two spaces vs. four due to internal standards.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import argparse
import logging
import string
import sys

from boto import vpc, exception

from lib.aws_location import LocationData
from lib.aws_util import check_config


def get_subnets(connection, vpc_id):
  """Function that returns all subnets within a given AWS VPC.
  :connection: AWS Connection.
  :vpc_id: VPC Identifier.

  """
  return connection.get_all_subnets(filters={'vpc_id': vpc_id})


def format_data(region, vpc_id, vpc_subnet, subnets):
  """Function that outputs region data based on template.

  :region: EC2 Region.
  :vpc_id: VPC Identifier.
  :vpc_subnet: Subnet allocated to VPC.
  :subnets: Subnets defined within VPC.

  todo:: Serialization. (yaml/json)
  """
  with open('vpc_subnets.tmpl') as f:
    templ = string.Template(f.read())

  region_dict = {}
  region_dict['region'] = region
  region_dict['vpc_id'] = vpc_id
  region_dict['vpc_subnet'] = vpc_subnet
  region_dict['subnets'] = ', '.join(subnets)

  print templ.safe_substitute(region_dict)


def parse_args():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description='Script for obtaining VPC Subnet information.')

  group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

  group.add_argument("-d", "--debug",
      help="Enable debug messages",
      action="store_true")

  group.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",
      help="Enable verbose messages",
      action="store_true")

  args = parser.parse_args()

  if args.debug:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
  elif args.verbose:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  else:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)

def main():
  parse_args()

  try:
    check_config()
  except EnvironmentError as e:
    print("Error: Could not open config file: {}".format(e))
    sys.exit(1)

  loc = LocationData()

  for region in loc.get_regions():
    try:
      connection = vpc.connect_to_region(region)
      for vpc_raw in loc.get_vpcs_raw(connection):
        vpc_id = str(vpc_raw).split(':')[1]
        subnets = []
        for subnet_id in get_subnets(connection, vpc_id):
          subnets.append(subnet_id.cidr_block)   
      format_data(region, vpc_id, vpc_raw.cidr_block, subnets)
    except exception.EC2ResponseError as e:
      logging.error("EC2Error: {}".format(e))
      continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used much `boto`, so I can just focus on some style comments:

- Use four spaces per indentation level
- Remove unused imports (`boto.exception`)
- Try to order imports in alphabetical order
- Move argument parsing and logging configuration code to separate functions
- Be careful of the usage of `next`. What you were probably looking for is `continue`, but you can just remove that line to move on to the next region in the loop
- `--dedug` and `--verbose` don't seem to make sense together. Have a look at `ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group`.
- Use a template or, at least, a multiline string to avoid writing so many `print` statements.

Comment: Awesome.. some great feedback. I have a few responses, so will update the comments in my review for others. Also, I plan to make some changes based on your feedback, so going to repost in a moment. Thank you so much for reviewing. Just one non-general notes - on the imports, they are ordered according to corelibs, 3rd party libs, then my custom libs. (pep8). That said I realize, I have one out of due import due to a rename.. :-(.

Comment: If you use `flake8`, you'll find the [`flake8-import-plugin`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8-import-order) useful.

Comment: Incorporated all of your suggestions - except for spacing (internal standards). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Note you're not supposed to update the question code in place because that makes the question less useful to other people in the future. More information [here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/8903)

Comment: Oh snap. Thanks for educating me. I figured someone might find the final solution helpful, but I definitely see the point of having a reference. Going to read up on that link, thanks for the info.